# What is the space complexity of duplicating the input?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, space-complexity

I have some strings as input and I need to manipulate their individual characters, which I do more efficiently by first splitting the strings into arrays of characters.
So in short, my algorithm is duplicating the input. What would be its space complexity?

Comment: You are splitting the strings into arrays of characters, so you are creating a 26-size char array and adding the characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same space complexity as the original problem.

If you have an input of n characters arranged in strings, that carries a spatial complexity of O(n). All you do is arrange them in some different way and duplicating the space you need: 2n and thus having a complexity of O(2n).

However O(n) is equivalent to O(kn), being k any constant. Doesn't mean both problems consume the same memory but complexity wise they are equivalent.

Comment: Actually I'm not creating a new data structure for each one given as input, so it can't be O(n). I've seen other problems in literature where the algorithm doesn't create any new data structures. For example, when it only manipulates an array that was given as the input. In those cases, according to literature, the space complexity is not O(n) but O(1). So taking your answer into consideration, the space complexity in the case of my question would be O(2*1), which is the same as O(1).

Comment: See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83574/does-space-complexity-analysis-usually-include-output-space/83586#83586